Unable to open document through office online application in SharePoint 2019 on premise
I am getting below error while opening any office document online
sorry, there was a problem, and we can't open this document, if this happens again try opening this document in Microsoft word while opening document through office online application.
Please help us in getting this resolved.
Thanks in advance.

Could you open the document in Microsoft Word?
